# If I use Powershell with "-NoLogo" to hide the "logo" text, can I be told/figure out if Powershell detected that I'm running an old version of pwsh?

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell 7 (core?) on Windows 10/11, and I get this kind of output when I start Windows Terminal:

```
PowerShell 7.2.3
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.

Loading personal and system profiles took 1860ms.
```

I know that I can configure Windows Terminal to start Powershell with the `-NoLogo` command line parameter, which hides this information.

**However**, if Powershell finds out that there is a new version out, it will embed something like the following into this same text:

```
A new Powershell stable release is available: v7.2.4
Upgrade now, or check out the release page at:
  https://aka.ms/Powershell-Release?tag=v7.2.4
```

Similar to this:

[image: Powershell update available]

If I use `-NoLogo`, this text disappears as well, and I would still like to be told. Basically, the `-NoLogo` option seems to just give me an all or nothing choice, and I would like to have a 3rd choice, "some".

So, is there any way I can do one of the following:

1. Get Powershell to start without the version information, link and help text, but still be told when a new version exists?
2. Or ... separately find out that a new version has been detected, like is there an environment variable or whatnot I can call manually?

I have some init-like scripts that runs here so I can easily embed code there, but I don't want to add the overhead of an https call to find this out.

For reference, but I doubt this is relevant, the configuration in Windows Terminal is like this:

```
{
    "guid": "{574e775e-4f2a-5b96-ac1e-a2962a402336}",
    "hidden": false,
    "name": "PowerShell",
    "source": "Windows.Terminal.PowershellCore"
},
```

I know I will have to change the `source` parameter to a `commandline` or similar to be able to pass parameters, but this I can handle.

Comment: Using winget, you could call `winget list microsoft.powershell` to see if there's an update available

Comment: I just noticed you don't want to make an extra http call, so my previous comment won't work

Comment: I'm thinking of adding a simple script that will run on startup and only do the check once a day, then I guess it would be OK to take the extra performance hit.

Comment: I have installed 7.2.2 right now, and it reports 7.2.3, so I can experiment a bit.

Comment: I ended up writing a powershell script that I run during init that will use the winget approach once a day to read the latest installable version, and then every invocation check if current version is older and then output some text. @Berend, if you would like to leave an answer with your approach then please do so and I'll accept it. I will also self-answer with my own script, but if you leave yours I will accept yours since you gave me the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to sacrifice some performance in exchange for an HTTP call, you could use winget:

`winget list microsoft.powershell`

If there is an update available, the output will contain a column named `Available`. If the installed version is up to date, you will only see columns Name, Id, Version and Source.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [@Berend's](https://superuser.com/users/361452/berend) comment about using `winget list microsoft.powershell` to write a script that will only retrieve available version once a day but do the comparison on every script execution.

***Disclaimer: I am a real life Powershell newbie so there's probably plenty in the following script that are not idiomatic optimal or just flat out error prone. I would love feedback to improve!***

```
$datafilepath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path), "Check-PowershellUpgrade-Data.json")
if (Test-Path $datafilepath) {
    $data = Get-Content $datafilepath | ConvertFrom-Json
} else {
    $data = @{ "date" = "0001-01-01"; "version" = "0.0.0.0" }
}
$today = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

if ($data.date -ne $today) {
    $lines = (winget list microsoft.powershell)
    foreach ($line in $lines) {
        $newversion = [regex]::match($line, "(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s+(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)").Groups[2].Value
        if ($newversion) {
            break
        }
    }
    if ($newversion) {
        $data.date = $today
        $data.version = $newversion
        $json = ConvertTo-Json $data
        Set-Content -Path $datafilepath -Value $json
    }
}

$currentversion = (Get-Host).Version
$majorMinorBuildOnly = [regex]::match($data.version, "^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.\d+$").Groups[1].Value
if ($majorMinorBuildOnly) {
    $installableversion = [System.Version]::Parse($majorMinorBuildOnly)
} else {
    $installableversion = [System.Version]::Parse($data.version)
}
if ($currentversion -lt $installableversion) {
    Write-Host "============================================================"
    Write-Host "A new PowerShell stable release is available: v$installableversion"
    Write-Host "Upgrade now, or check out the release page at:"
    Write-Host "  https://aka.ms/PowerShell-Release?tag=v$installableversion"
    Write-Host "============================================================"
}
```